# Navigator routes Clear the stack of flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In my app i have three screens login , verifyotp , generatepass. I know how to move from one page to other page eg: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/theNameOfThePage");`.
I have a flow in which i move from login->verifyotp->generatepass my question is now how can i move from generatepass  to login page and clearing all the stack.
I am an android developer so in android we have `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`.
How can i achieve same result in flutter!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Full clean of Navigator's history and navigate to new route:

```
void _logout() {
   Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/newRouteName", (r) => false);
}
```

Comment: By respect, I think This is better answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575473/rebuild-app-or-delete-cache-when-redirect-to-home-page-flutter

Comment: @MrSalesi I don't see an answer in your linked SO question. Are you referring to the EDIT in your linked SO question?

Answer (score 26):

Use [`Navigator.popUntil`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html).

```
void _logout() {
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
}
```

Comment: `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));`  worked for me !!   my login page has  `routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      "/VerifyOtp": (BuildContext context) => new VerifyOtp(),
      "/GeneratePass": (BuildContext context) => new GeneratePass(),
    },`

Answer (score 13):

As others have already mentioned, `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` is the way to go, but in case if anyone is wondering how to do that using the component type (instead of a string route path), this is how you do it.

> Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)
> => LoginPage()), (route) => false);

I personally prefer using the type name because I change my route path multiple times during the initial development until I reach a stable route name pattern and when I do that, I don't want to do a mass search/replace.

Answer (score 8):

To add to [Paul Iluhin's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57030299/7145285), if you want to pass arguments to the new page, just add the arguments after `(r) => false`. Here is an example.

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/newRouteName", (r) => false, arguments: {
  "arg_1": firstArgument,
  "arg_2": secondArgument
});
```

Comment: Thanks dear, I appreciate your answer, it works :)