# Flutter : finish all the screen/activity (for android/iOS both)

Tags: flutter, activity-finish, flutter-ios, flutter-android

How can I finish all the activity/screen in Flutter.

I want it for Android and iOS.

Is there any way to same like **finishAffinity()** in Android we do.

Example:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> Force Logout -> Open Login Screen and close all previous screen.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigator routes Clear the stack of flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071933/navigator-routes-clear-the-stack-of-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, yourRouteToLogin, (route) => false);
```

or if you have named routes:

```
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context, yourRouteName, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Comment: This one helps me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using named routes, you can do this like that:
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (route) => false);`.

Answer (score 0):

For those not using string named routes... The above didnt work for me.

***Instead do this....***

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyLoginPage()), (route) => false);
```

I had to do some RnD... but this works fine