# Rebuild app or delete cache when redirect to home page Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have an app where when I logout with Firebase Auth, user's datas are **still there**, and I need to Hot restart the app to totally remove them.

I didn’t find a way to improve the signout method, so I want to try to rebuild app when user logout, or maybe delete the cache so user’s datas will no longer exist in app.

I have done some research but I can’t find any solution that can help me.

EDIT : Here's how I logout

```
    Future<void> signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signOut()
        .then((value) => print('Sign Out'))
        .onError((error, stackTrace) => print('Error in signed out'));
  }
```

```
 IconButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await signOut();
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                              .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return const OnBoardingPage();
                              },
                            ),
                            (_) => false,
                          );
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))
```

I know that user's data are still there because I can display `user.email` in my onBoardingPage (where technically no data can be there because I logout previously).

Here a preview of my onBoardingPage : [image: preview onBoardingPage]

After that, if I want to connect with another account, I will be connected to the previous user's session. The same if I want to create a new account, all new user's data will be into the previous connected user. To fix this problem, in development mode, I need to hot restart the app.

It seems like the user is not totally logout.

Comment: The question is a bit vague - when the user signs out using Firebase authentication, what data is still there - local data? Data in Firebase? Can you provide details as to what data that is?

Comment: the user is still connected when he logout, I need to Hot Restart the app. The session is still active, all datas of user are in Firebase.

Comment: Questions here on SO generally contain the code involved in the issue but there's no code so we don't know what process is being used. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with a minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue. In other words you could just be doing it wrong which is causing the problem but we don't know that. Including code clarifies the issue.

Comment: Much better. Now, can you explain, in your question, what - *some data of user is still there* - means specifically? What *data* remains? How do you know it's there? What process did you use to reveal that data? Please be specific so we understand the issue.

Comment: One thing to check is if the user was actually logged out with some code like this`firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {   console.log('Signed Out'); }, function(error) {   console.error('Sign Out Error', error); });`.  I don't know your platform but the other thing is that Firebase persists the user info on the device (Keychain on iOS for example) and there's some general info here [Persisting authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#persisting-authentication-state). That being said, if there's not auth'd user then don't display that email?

Comment: Ok so I've edited OP with your advice, and I've "Signed Out" in my console. For now, I develop on Android. So, if I understood correctly your link, the persistent auth state can't be configure. Also, if no there is auth'd user, I've an error because the app can't displayed the `user.email` on my onBoarding Page  (and it is normal because no user is log). But I don't know why there is this persistent session after logout.